# How to identify which files have changed between git commits

Tags: git, go, continuous-delivery, monorepo, go-git

How can we use go-git to generate a list of all the files that have changed between two commits similar to `git diff --name-only commit1 commit2`?

For context, we have a git monorepo that contains a single root `go.mod` file but multiple Go applications. When developers push commits to a branch, we would like to get a list of all files that changed between two git commits (`git diff --name-only`), and filter it down into a list of application directories while excluding some directories. Our ultimate goal is so we can build, deploy, and test just the applications that have changed inside our monorepo. We have a [bash script similar to this one from shippable](https://github.com/devops-recipes/app-mono/blob/master/detect-changed-services.sh) that does this, but we'd like to use pure go and go-git.

Comment: You might need to build it yourself using [Tree.Diff](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object#Tree.Diff).

Comment: I've updated your title to match the new question, too.

Comment: TBH, having one repo for multiple applications sounds odd to me in the first place. Have multiple repos each with their own CI, and if you absolutely must, have a "parent" repo which contains the other repos as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Additionally, given that the Go compiler is explicitly optimised for compilation speed (and I rarely have seen any Go program that takes longer than a few seconds to compile), I fail to see the advantage. Like in "at all".

Comment: TBH, I agree with you @MarkusWMahlberg but I'm tasked with making the monorepo work, not with deciding whether to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `change.Files()` gives only the names of the files with `to.Name`, without the paths inside the repository, however the `change.toString()` gives the full path.

So if you want to use [Tree.Diff](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object#Tree.Diff), you have to get the paths like this:

```
func getChangeName(change *object.Change) string {
        var empty = object.ChangeEntry{}
        if change.From != empty {
            return change.From.Name
        }

        return change.To.Name
}
```

So with that, it looks like you can choose either [Tree.Diff](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object#Tree.Diff) or [Patch.Stats](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object#Patch.Stats) depending on your needs:

```
    currentTree, err := commit.Tree()
    CheckIfError(err)

    prevTree, err := prevCommit.Tree()
    CheckIfError(err)

    patch, err := currentTree.Patch(prevTree)
    CheckIfError(err)
    fmt.Println("----- Patch Stats ------")

    var changedFiles []string
    for _, fileStat := range patch.Stats() {
        fmt.Println(fileStat.Name)
        changedFiles = append(changedFiles,fileStat.Name)
    }

    changes, err := currentTree.Diff(prevTree)
    CheckIfError(err)
    fmt.Println("----- Changes -----")
    for _, change := range changes {
        // Ignore deleted files
        action, err := change.Action()
        CheckIfError(err)
        if action == merkletrie.Delete {
            //fmt.Println("Skipping delete")
            continue
        }
        // Get list of involved files
        name := getChangeName(change)
        fmt.Println(name)
    }
```

[Patch.Stats](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object#Patch.Stats) will skip binary files, where [Tree.Diff](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object#Tree.Diff) will let you ignore deletions.